# Facebook Like button and Google Plus Badge are not working in an HTML table

Tags: html, facebook, facebook-like

I want to use facebook Like button and Google+ badge on my website.
I added this code for this purpose:

```
<table align='right'>
    <tr>
        <td align='right'>
        <div class="fb-like" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/RideForHealth" data-send="true" data-layout="box_count" data-width="100" data-show-faces="true"></div>

        </td>
        <td>
        <g:plus href="https://plus.google.com/107539471286877449345" rel="publisher" width="300" height="131" theme="light"></g:plus>
        </td>

    </tr>
</table>
```

But this is not working. I click on buttons but nothing happens.
When I remove the HTML table, both work perfectly alright.
Here is the [website](http://ride4health.weebly.com/) for which I am using this.

Answer (score 0):

I would say try this plugin for google badge

i am using it on my wordpress its working for me..

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/kd-google-plus-badge/

Answer (score 0):

I think you forget to add this js in your head...

```
  (function() {
    var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
    po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
  })();
```